# Adding a unchanged file to Git

Tags: git

I pushed a plugin after modifications which got updated in the plugin update. Now I want to update the plugin back to the changes I made. The problem is I can't add these files to Git since to Git these files are committed. How do I add the complete plugin folder to it?

Comment: If there are no changes, then what are you trying to do? Please add more detail.

Comment: There were changes which were pushed but the plugin got updated.

Comment: I don't understand what that means. How is "updated" different than "pushed"? Rather than more comments, please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: How did you get on with the below answer, Fahad? It looks helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems a bit ambiguous, but it sounds like this might be what happened?

- You added an off-the-shelf piece of code to your repo and committed it
- You made custom changes to it and committed those
- You downloaded a new version of it and committed that, but it's now lost your custom changes as a result
- You've tried adding your custom changes back in with git-merge, but Git says it's already aware of them, because of that earlier commit

So it sounds like you're currently probably trying to git-merge your original changes, and it's not having it, because they're already in its history.  Instead, you can `git checkout [the commit hash for your changes] [the affected file]`.  By specifying the file to checkout, you're telling Git you want to stay where you are.  You're not really changing the branch you're on or looking at a previous commit, you're just overwriting a particular file or set of files.

Now you'll be able to see your changes again with git-diff, but you can't commit them because it will undo the other person's changes.  So you need to manually reconcile the two, or use `git add -p` to go step-by-step and say which changes of yours to keep and which undoing of their code to discard.  That way, you can keep both your changes and their changes.  Then you can commit it as a new commit that mixes and matches what you both did.